# django - render_to_response - some stuff is rendered

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, django-views

This is a very simple problem but I just can't figure it out.

I have view which fetches a row and then invokes render_to_response on it. However I want to add some other stuff for display in the template which has not come from the database. I just can't work out how to do that and I can't find anything in the documentation which covers this situation.

Everything works as it should do if I just pass the results of the database fetch - the form gets rendered etc. As soon as I introduce some other stuff I either get a 500 (as in the example below) or it just gets completely ignored.

*(The stuff I'm working on in the examples shown below is a sort of mutation of the django tutorial 'polls' app so apologies if some of the naming seems a bit odd)*

**VIEW**

As well as the BookMark object I add some arbitary data, in my example a string 'test title'.

```
def detail(request, bookmark_id):
    try:
        b = BookMark.objects.get(pk=bookmark_id)
        d = {'title' = 'test title'}
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render_to_response(  'bookmarks/bookmark_detail.html',
            {'bookmark': b, 'title': d},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**BASE TEMPLATE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Default Title from base.html{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topstuff">
            <h1>This is top stuff</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div id="bottomstuff">
            <h1>This is bottom stuff</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**INNER TEMPLATE**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{{ bookmark }}


{% block title %}{{ title.title }}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

    {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

    <form action="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/vote/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>URL:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="{{ bookmark.url }}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TITLE:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{{ bookmark.title }}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>NOTES:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="notes" id="notes" value="{{ bookmark.notes }}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

{% endblock content%}
```

---

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in the comments I had a typo there so just for the sake of future searchers either of the following two approaches works:

***OPTION 1***
Embed value directly into dictionary passed to render_to_response as follows

```
return render_to_response(  'bookmarks/bookmark_detail.html',
        {'bookmark': b, 'title':'test title1'},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Refer to that value within the template as follows:

```
{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock title %}
```

***OPTION2***
Create a container dictionary to hold other values and then embed that into the dictionary passed to render_to_response as follows

```
d = {'title':'test title 2'}
return render_to_response(  'bookmarks/bookmark_detail.html',
        {'bookmark': b, 'title':d},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Refer to that value within the template as follows:

```
{% block title %}{{ title.title }}{% endblock title %}
```

Comment: Syntax error: `d = {'title' = 'test title'}` inside your `detail` function

Comment: please close the question if you have a solution (add your solution as an answer and mark it as the selected answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments I had a typo there so just for the sake of future searchers either of the following two approaches works:

***OPTION 1***
Embed value directly into dictionary passed to render_to_response as follows

```
return render_to_response(  'bookmarks/bookmark_detail.html',
        {'bookmark': b, 'title':'test title1'},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Refer to that value within the template as follows:

```
{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock title %}
```

***OPTION2***
Create a container dictionary to hold other values and then embed that into the dictionary passed to render_to_response as follows

```
d = {'title':'test title 2'}
return render_to_response(  'bookmarks/bookmark_detail.html',
        {'bookmark': b, 'title':d},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Refer to that value within the template as follows:

```
{% block title %}{{ title.title }}{% endblock title %}
```